# Does pgAdmin4 Have an arm64 Build?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I've followed these instructions for pgAdmin4 and was able to install it on an x86_64 server but not on an arm64 server. https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

We're running Postgres 10 on Ubuntu 18.04. Also, pgAdmin3 works on arm64.

When I run sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop, I get the following. Is there an arm64 version of pgAdmin4?

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package pgadmin4-desktop is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'pgadmin4-desktop' has no installation candidate

Comment: // https://hub.docker.com/r/biarms/pgadmin4/tags // hi I solved the problem using the docker container

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a way to run pgadmin4 on my arm64 based chromebook.

It should work on many environment.

```
# Install docker
# from https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/
sudo apt-get install \
  ca-certificates \
  curl \
  gnupg \
  lsb-release
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin

# pull the pgadmin4
sudo docker pull biarms/pgadmin4:latest
```

To run pgadmin4 you can

```
sudo docker run -p 5050:5050 biarms/pgadmin4:latest
```

Now you can access `localhost:5050` and your pgadmin4 should show up.

Comment: I serve my db on a vps, with an ip. I installed this docker as you instructed on that server. I can now open the pgadmin, but how can i connect to the db? What should I put in the host address? localhost? 127.0.0.1? or the vps ip? i tried all, did not work.

Comment: @Vahid You should be able to connect with remote server IP, but port 5050 should be open so check that. I think it's not postgres specific, so find a way to allow access for your Linux distro.